# Error importing "openwisp_utils.admin import ReadOnlyAdmin"

Tags: django, python-3.x, openwisp

I am trying to implement django-freeradius, but I get the error *cannot import name 'ReadOnlyAdmin'*, when I write the line * in urlspatters within urls.py of my project. I have tried to use the same configuration in https://github.com/openwisp/django-freeradius/blob/master/tests/urls.py, but it does not work.

```
# myproject/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from openwisp_utils.admin_theme.admin import admin, openwisp_admin

openwisp_admin()
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('django_freeradius.urls', namespace='freeradius')), #* This line
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I have installed:
Python 3.6.8
Django 2.2.4
django-filter 2.1.0
django-freeradius 0.1a0
openwisp-utils 0.2.2

These are my apps in settings.py

```
# myproject/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_freeradius',
    'django_filters',
]
```

And, this is the complete error when I run *python manage.py runserver* ()

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/src/django-freeradius/django_freeradius/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base.admin import (
  File "/mnt/c/Users/myuser/Documents/python/hotspot/env/src/django-freeradius/django_freeradius/base/admin.py", line 9, in <module>
    from openwisp_utils.admin import ReadOnlyAdmin, TimeReadonlyAdminMixin
ImportError: cannot import name 'ReadOnlyAdmin'
```

I appreciate if someone could give me the reason of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install the development version of openwisp-utils:

```
pip install --upgrade http://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-utils/tarball/master
```